# autoscaling pods in kubernetes by heapster

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, heapster

I want to auto scale my pod in **kubernetes**. after some research I understand that i should use **heapster** for monitoring. what tested document you can suggest.
how can i test it?
i know i should use some stress test but does any one has document about it?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Heapster is EOL. https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster

> RETIRED: Heapster is now retired. See the deprecation timeline for more information on support. We will not be making changes to Heapster.

The following are potential migration paths for Heapster functionality:

```
For basic CPU/memory HPA metrics: Use metrics-server.

For general monitoring: Consider a third-party monitoring pipeline that can gather Prometheus-formatted metrics. The kubelet exposes all the metrics exported by Heapster in Prometheus format. One such monitoring pipeline can be set up using the Prometheus Operator, which deploys Prometheus itself for this purpose.

For event transfer: Several third-party tools exist to transfer/archive Kubernetes events, depending on your sink. heptiolabs/eventrouter has been suggested as a general alternative.
```

Comment: thanks
but how can i use 3
what document do you try